# New method to a class outside of the class definition

Tags: python, class, methods

In Python, does anyone know of a nicer way of overriding a method of instantiated object that would give the function access to the class instance (self) and all its methods/properties?

The one below works, but somehow I do not like how use the global scope to pass object a to the `new_f`.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 10
  def f(self):
    return 2 + self.b
  def g(self):
    print(self.f())

a = A()

# simple override case
a.f = lambda: 10 
a.g()

# now I want to have access to property b of the object a
# but it also could be a method of object the object a
def new_f():
  self = a
  return 10+self.b

a.f = new_f
a.g()
```

Comment: *monkey patching* in python is explained here: https://thecodebits.com/monkey-patching-in-python-explained-with-examples/ (one of many resources...)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it was called this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution depending on your use case would be to define the function with `self` as an argument like `def new_f(self)` and then `define A.f = new_f` before initializing object `a`.

Comment: Actually it works for me, having it on the class before creating the object is ok in my use case. Just did not think about it this way. Thanks.